# Query regarding not in clause?

Tags: sql

Hi I am running query on two files File1 and File 2 Having fields a,b,c and d,e,f respectively .A and D & B and E are of same type and are keys in the files. So i am running a query to find out all those records of File1 which are not present in File2. I am running the join on the basis to fields a,b and d,e.But some how its not working :

```
select * from file1 where a,b not in ((select a,b from file1 x,file2 y where y.a=x.d
 and y.b=x.e) z)
```

It says not in clause not correct then i tried:

```
select * from file1 where not exists (select a,b from file1 x,file2 y where y.a=x.d
     and y.b=x.e)
```

It is also not working !!! Please suggest !I am on DB2 AS400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM file1 f1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM file2 f2
                         WHERE f1.a = f2.d
                             AND f1.b = f2.e)
```

You could also do this with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT f1.*
    FROM file1 f1
        LEFT JOIN file2 f2
            ON f1.a = f2.d
                AND f1.b = f2.e
    WHERE f2.d IS NULL
```

Comment: I am not able to understand why we are using null also both the queries are not working :(... Please make me understand a bit

Comment: I want all the records except that in table 2

Comment: @abhinavsingh: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? No error but no results? The NULL in the first query is arbitrary. You could `SELECT 1` instead and get the same results. The NULL in the second query however is important as it indicates that the LEFT JOIN did not find a matching row in file2.

Comment: Not working means i ran the second one and its giving all the records of file 1

Comment: @abhinavsingh And what does the first query return?

Comment: Its giving error while selecting NULL as we cannot select NULL in db2

Comment: @abhinavsingh As I mentioned in my previous comment, you should be able to change that to `SELECT 1` without changing the meaning/results of the query.

Comment: Thanks Man it worked but i am completely unable to understand the query ...Please brief me little bit so that i can understand how its working !!

Answer (score 0):

DO a simple join and apply a WHERE clause where NULL in the second table...

```
select
      F1.a,
      F1.b,
      F1.c
   from
      File1 F1
         left join File2 F2
            on F1.a = F2.d
           and F1.b = F2.e
   where
      F2.d is null
```